# What is the horizontal scrolling in the Android Market app called?

Tags: android, view, google-play, horizontal-scrolling

In the new Android Market app (version 3.3.11), they have made it possible to switch between the different tabs (Featured, Top Paid, Top Free, etc.). I want to implement something like this in my own app.

My aim is to switch between two activities using the same horizontal scrolling technique as the Android Market app is using. The problem is, I can't find out what the technique is called.

Any help is much apprectiated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at [Horizontal View Swiping with ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) article.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll check it out in a few hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) is an Android UI widget providing a horizontally scrollable ViewGroup with items populated from an Adapter.

[image: Example]

Comment: You shouldn't use custom created stuff, when there's a ViewPager directly within the provided APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Well in new Android Market App, I have seen **Carousel**. You can also read about Gallery View.